# Does this bracket exist to hold two tiles together?

Tags: metal

I don't think it's the best title, but I don't know what else to use.

I have several of [these large tiles](https://www.homedepot.com/p/MSI-Paradiso-Cream-20-in-x-20-in-Polished-Porcelain-Floor-and-Wall-Tile-19-44-sq-ft-case-NPARCREAM20X20/202598229), and I want to make a planter out of them. Is there a bracket (like the image below) that I can put in each corner that will hold these five tiles together so that they stay together?

If not, how can I attach five tiles so that they stay together and *remain* together?

It will be used as a planter. The brackets could be on the inside or the outside.

[image]

Comment: Epoxy and square wood blocks on the inside of the cube. Is that an option?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Or epoxy and metal brackets on the inside. But inside will hold and look better than outside.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean, that's a good idea, but it would have to be something that's not made out of wood. It will be used as a planter.

Comment: Look at these.   https://www.us.playwood.it/

Comment: What plant are you putting in it? What is your weight limit for the planter+soil?

Comment: Alaska Man, that's a good answer and maybe should go into the answer field. Those little plastic brackets are pretty expensive, if one is building a large assembly, but for a planter, maybe not too bad. I'd think 16 pieces at about US$15  for four eats up the budget pretty quickly. A six-pack of four pieces comes in a bit cheaper at about US$75.  It might spur other ideas from the OP, though. My first thought is 3D printed brackets might be less costly.

Comment: Aha! Now I see it is a planter and not some random "box". So the pressure will come from the inside - and therefore brackets on the outside make sense. Dirt weighs a *lot*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just buy some 2"x 3" or 3"x3" aluminum angle and cut off 2" pieces and drill holes in each side.

You could get a lot of brackets from a long piece of angle and epoxy them to the tiles. Aluminum is soft enough to cut with hacksaw .

You could use a diamond drill bit to drill the tiles and  dill holes in the angle to attach the brackets with machine bolts.

OR

Look at these. [Playwood](https://www.us.playwood.it/)