# Are these corner brackets that hard-to-find?

Tags: metal, brackets

I was searching for this a particular corner brace/bracket, but it seems that they are impossible to find.

I couldn't them at home depot or at amazon. I'm not sure if they just don't exist or if I'm looking for them incorrectly.

This is it:

[image]

I posted a [similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/172419/does-this-bracket-exist-to-hold-two-tiles-together/172427#172427), and it helped because it showed me an alternative, but in this case I want to find this specific bracket that will hold three *walls* together.

Comment: So search, this is a quick result so they do exist https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Pack-50-heavy-duty-enclosed-corner-brace-angle-brackets-fixing-repair-plate-50mm/202654691087?hash=item2f2f292f0f:g:~ZUAAOSwH6lXQ182

Comment: I agree they are easy to find but possibly the op has dimensions that are specific I don’t see in the question. Mike turn that into an answer and remember link only tend to change and be worthless or I would have up voted your comment but some folks don’t know what corner brackets are. Even it is in the question some may have missed that.

Comment: Agree with Ed. That's an answer. The OP is still trying to make those planters.. lol

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: how about using steamer trunk corners? https://www.hardwaretree.com/products.php?cat=Corners+for+Trunks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this one on Amazon:
https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B071W4VQPT 
You are working with a 20x20 tile and these are 2.25" Roughly

These ones: https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0195UGD38
They are much larger, though WAY more Expensive.

Though you will see those Brackets. You could use something like this on the Inside with some Galv Bolts or SS Screws to make it look nicer. 
https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07CWMSS79

I'd put two on each adjoining edge. so 2 in each corner and 2 on each side on the bottom.